# CiviCRM still creates MyISAM tables which results in Warning

Tags: database, mysql, 4.7.10

*CiviCRM 4.7.10 --- WordPress 4.6*

The following warning message appeared in **CiviCRM System Status**:

> Your database is configured to use the MyISAM database engine. CiviCRM
>   requires InnoDB. You will need to convert any MyISAM tables in your
>   database to InnoDB. Using MyISAM tables will result in data integrity
>   issues.

This message appeared 5 days after upgrading to 4.7.10 from 4.7.8. The table with the MyISAM engine was: **civicrm_task_action_temp%**. I corrected it in MySQL using:

```
ALTER TABLE civicrm_task_action_temp% ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

On inspecting the code, I found the following in **civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Contact\Form\Task.php on line 145**

> $sql = "CREATE TABLE {$form->_componentTable} ( contact_id int primary
>   key) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE
>   utf8_unicode_ci";

and **civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Export\BAO\Export.php on line 1494**

> CREATE TABLE {$exportTempTable} ( ... ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT
>   CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

All other MyISAM tables are defined as TEMPORARY.

Prior to performing the upgrade, I cleaned the caches using **CiviCRM/System Settings/Cleanup Caches and Update Paths**. Hence the reason **civicrm_task_action_temp%** was recreated.

Hopefully, this fix can be included in the next update.

Comment: It also happened to me after 4.7.10 upgrade on Joomla! 3.6.2. Ty.

Comment: There's an old issue in JIRA that looks like it's related to this. I've seen this error pop up recently, but I'm trying to remember if I was working on a 4.7 site or a 4.6 one. It might be worth reopening the issue or creating an new one and flagging it related. https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15601

Comment: Happened on upgrade to 4.7.10 with Drupal as well.

Comment: Also on upgrade to 4.7.11 with Joomla.

Comment: I mean 4.7.10 of course

Comment: This issue is still not fixed in 4.7.11

Answer (score 2):

Based on Dan's pointer to https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15601 , it seems like this used to work. It probably regressed with https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/3fa9688a5 which introduced a very subtle change to how it ignores temp tables. Compare:

- (Old) `strpos($dao->Name, '_temp') !== FALSE`
- (New) `TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%temp'`

Proposed fix: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/8930