# I am suddenly receiving the message, "Your database is configured to use the MyISAM database engine

Tags: mysql

I am suddenly receiving the message, "Your database is configured to use the MyISAM database engine. CiviCRM requires InnoDB. You will need to convert any MyISAM tables in your database to InnoDB. Using MyISAM tables will result in data integrity issues.

I'm running 5.26.1

How will this affect my Wordpress site?

Thank,
dt

Comment: Can you run `show table status where engine like '%ISAM%';` on your database, e.g. using phpmyadmin or command line? It will tell you what tables it's talking about.

Comment: Thanks so much Demerit! Turns out the tables in question are from the CiviElection extension. I've decided not to use that extension in favor of a WP plugin, so will delete that extension and see if message goes away.

Comment: That did it. All is well. (For now) Thanks again.

Comment: Ok cool. It's unlikely that extension specifically creates MyISAM tables and more likely it just doesn't specify, so it's probably that the system default is set to MyISAM, e.g. `show variables like 'default_storage_engine';`

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too after upgrading from 5.52.3 to 5.60. This post showed how to fix the 5 temp tables in my system:
[CiviCRM still creates MyISAM tables which results in Warning](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14444/civicrm-still-creates-myisam-tables-which-results-in-warning)
It looked like this:
mysql> alter table civicrm_temp_2281c543efe9ebaa8e9fd6331f53600d ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 9274 rows affected (0.13 sec)
Records: 9274  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
I did that for each InnoDB table it found.
Should I change the default_storage_engine global from InnoDB to ISAM?

Comment: Yes - I think it's a good idea to "change the default_storage_engine global from InnoDB to ISAM?"

Also - your default charset should be utf8mb4 (not sure if that is relevant, just mentioning it)